# Here Maps API - iOS SDK - Rendering lines below zoom level 16

Tags: ios, here-api

I've setup a HERE Maps NMAMapView in my iOS project to provide an interactive map. When I started adding NMAMapPolylines to the map I found they don't seem to render at zoom level 16 and below, regardless of visibility settings.

This is a problem since the lines should only render when zoomed in (there are 200,000 of them, so I don't want to render them while zoomed out).

In order to rule out any stupidity on my part, since I do have some complicated view-culling code, I've added a line and a polygon to the 'HelloMap' sample app without doing anything special to the objects. The NMAMapCircle and NMAMapPolygon objects continue to render when passing zoom level 16, but the NMAMapPolyline stops rendering.

Is there something that needs to be enabled in the SDK to get the lines to render? Or is this a known bug?

I've tried Googling but cannot find the question raised elsewhere.

Comment: which api you using default mapkit api or google map?

Comment: Neither. I've had to port from the default mapkit to another provider called HERE Maps.

I'm using the SDK provided by the "HERE_iOS_SDK_Starter_v3.0.1.tar.gz" download.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really fixed but is no longer an issue. My company upgraded the SDK from the starter/trial version to the premium version and the premium version doesn't have the issue.